# Unknown string from Dynamic Loaded Golang to CPP

Tags: c++, go, cgo, dynamic-loading

So, I tried to run my go code on C++ project with dynamic loading. It's working great, except there is some unwanted string on returned value. As I explained down, I got some information from Go that unwanted.

My go code:

```
package main

import "C"

func main() {}

//export GetTestString
func GetTestString() string {
    return "test"
}
```

I build it with:
`go build -buildmode=c-shared -o test.so test.go`

Dynamically load it on my CPP project with this function:

```
typedef struct { const char *p; ptrdiff_t n; } GoString;

void getTestString() {
    void *handle;
    char *error;
    handle = dlopen ("./test.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        fputs (dlerror(), stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    // resolve getTestString symbol and assign to fn ptr
    auto getTestString = (GoString (*)())dlsym(handle, "GetTestString");
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
        fputs(error, stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    // call GetTestString()
    GoString testString = (*getTestString)();
    printf("%s\n", testString.p);

    // close file handle when done
    dlclose(handle);
}
```

Output is:

> "**test**true ...\n H_T= H_a= H_g= MB,  W_a= and  cnt= h_a= h_g= h_t= max= ptr  siz= tab= top= u_a= u_g=, ..., fp:argp=falsefaultgcingpanicsleepsse41sse42ssse3 (MB)\n addr= base  code= ctxt: curg= goid  jobs= list= m->p= next= p->m= prev= span= varp=(...)\n, not SCHED efenceerrno objectpopcntscvg: selectsweep  (scan  (scan) MB in  dying= locks= m->g0= nmsys= s=nil\n, goid=, size=, sys: GODEBUGIO waitSignal \ttypes \tvalue=cs     fs     gctracegs     panic: r10    r11    r12    r13    r14    r15    r8     r9     rax    rbp    rbx    rcx    rdi    rdx    rflags rip    rsi    rsp    runningsignal syscallunknownwaiting etypes  goalΔ= is not  mcount= minutes nalloc= newval= nfree..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing strings via pointer to C you need either use length (`n`) in `GoString` to fetch right number of characters as string at `p` is not `\0` terminated. Or you can return `*C.char` instead of `string` and use `C.CString()` to allocate copy on C heap (which you then are responsible for freeing after use). See Cgo documentation [here](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo#hdr-Go_references_to_C).

What is happening in your code is that `printf()` simply prints all characters starting from location pointed to by `string.p` until it hits `\0` terminator - that's why you see contents of memory after `test`.

So you can do either something like:

```c
printf("%.*s\n", testString.n, testString.p);
```

(but note that most functions that operate on C strings which are expected to be `\0` terminated will not work on this pointer unless they also take length of string)

or change Go part to something like this and then `free()` pointer after use on C side:

```golang
func GetTestString() *C.char {
    return C.CString("test") // CString will allocate string on C heap
}
```